# not able to use ThoughtWorks namespace after adding a reference of ThoughtWorks.Selenium.core

Tags: c#, selenium, sharpdevelop

i have added a Reference of ThoughtWorks.Selenium.core.dll to my project but the project gives me an error while

```
using ThoughtWorks.Selenium.core;
```

> Error: The type or namespace name 'ThoughtWorks' could not be found

Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.0 (Not .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile)
I'm using Sharp Developer tool not Visual Studio

what am i doing Wrong?

Comment: What framework is the ThoughtWorks.Selenium.core targeting? Also are you sure its not ThoughtWorks.Selenium.**C**ore ???

Comment: It is ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the assembly name is ThoughtWorks.Selenium.core the assembly itself does not have any namespaces using that name. All the types are in a Selenium namespace. So you should change your using statement to:

```
using Selenium;
```

I downloaded the C# client driver from http://www.seleniumhq.org/